# Google Drive api3 deleting folder

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I have a simple question. What will happen id I delete a parent folder ID . All its sub folder and files will be deleted ?
I tried such a delete . It looks like all sub folders and contents vanished from the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you're the owner of those descendent files, they will be deleted too. See the explanation for [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete):

> Permanently deletes a file owned by the user without moving it to the trash. If the file belongs to a shared drive the user must be an organizer on the parent. **If the target is a folder, all descendants owned by the user are also deleted**.

#### Reference:

- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete)